# mod rewrite rule for complicated 301 redirects

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

So I'm doing a site with around 4,000 products and urls are changing from there old site and don't fancy making 301 rules for each one so I've done the following to move categories (examples below)

```
# Main Categories
RewriteRule ^(.*)home-page-categories/name-1\.html$ name-1/ [R=301,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)home-page-categories/name-2\.html$ name-2/ [R=301,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)home-page-categories/name-3\.html$ name-3/ [R=301,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)home-page-categories/name-4\.html$ name-4/ [R=301,NC,L]
```

So the above makes the `home-page-categories/name-1.html` into a single directory `/name-1/` - great!

```
# Artist Categories from Root Categories
RewriteRule ^(.*)home-page-categories/name-1/(.*)\.html$ name-1/$2/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)home-page-categories/name-2/(.*)\.html$ name-2/$2/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)home-page-categories/name-3/(.*)\.html$ name-3/$2/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)home-page-categories/name-4/(.*)\.html$ name-4/$2/ [R=301,L]
```

The over then grabs the secondary categories such as `/home-page-categories/name-1/example.html` and make it `name-1/example/` - great!

However on the next level I need to carry the product name so it would be:

`/home-page-categories/name-1/example/product.html` and make it `name-1/example/product.html` but the rule above I think might conflict with that.

Any ideas on a rule that can handle this all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To keep in line with your examples, a solution could be, for `name-1`

```
RewriteRule home-page-categories/name-1\.html$ /name-1/ [R=301,NC,L]
RewriteRule home-page-categories/name-1/([^/]+)\.html$ /name-1/$1/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule home-page-categories/name-1/(.*)\.html$ /name-1/$1.html [R=301,L]
```

Depending on what you wish to achieve, you could replace all your rules with

```
RewriteRule home-page-categories/([^/]+)\.html$ /$1/ [R=301,NC,L]
RewriteRule home-page-categories/([^/]+)/([^/]+)\.html$ /$1/$2/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule home-page-categories/(.*\.html)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Or with more specific rules

```
RewriteRule home-page-categories/(name-1|name-2|name-3|name-4)\.html$ /$1/ [R=301,NC,L]
RewriteRule home-page-categories/(name-1|name-2|name-3|name-4)/([^/]+)\.html$ /$1/$2/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule home-page-categories/((name-1|name-2|name-3|name-4)/.*\.html)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that for you is better solution to do this type of rewrite in PHP code. If you don't know how tell me and I will update this post and add some examples.